# Sas dates format-yymmn6. is not recognised in excel. what is the easiest way out?

Tags: excel, sas

I wanted to automate a bunch of calculations in SAS for ultimately doing a chart in excel. In this process, I have dates as the column names . So to sort them according to the dates I used this format- yymmn6. Format to get eg 201604- year, month so that I can sort by dates(dd was always01) . And added a prefix C_.

```
     C_201406   C_201407    C_201408    C_201409    C_201410 ....
MAX     8      5.681818    4.291845    3.755725     2.281169 ....
…
```

I arrange everything in this order. I perform all the calculations ready. When I paste the data in Excel, I removed the prefix C_. The dates are not recognized correctly. For eg-201406 is considered as 6/5/2451.
For my charts I want it in this format Jun-14.
I am not sure if it is easy to do the change in excel or change originally in SAS and also arrange in an order. I want to know how to do this to achieve finally in a format where dates are Jun-14(mmm-YY)?

Comment: For your variables, create a LABEL in SAS that shows as Jun-14. Then when you export use the LABEL option to have the labels written to Excel, not the variable name. You can likely skip the remove the C_ option in this case.  If you need help with the code, post back and I can help later, if someone hasn't already.

Comment: I'm not sure what your whole process looks like, depending on how you're processing the data where exactly you add the label may make this very easy or slightly more work. Ie if you have a Transpose at some point the IDLABEL option will make this super easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two repair routines. The first loops through each cell, repairing them as it goes; the second repairs the first cell and uses it in a series fill.

[image]

```
Sub wqewhgwq()
    Dim yymmm6 As Range
    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(1, "B").End(xlToRight))
            For Each yymmm6 In .Cells
                yymmm6 = DateSerial(Mid(yymmm6.Value2, 3, 4), Right(yymmm6.Value2, 2), 1)
            Next yymmm6
            .NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub fgsaewrt()
    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(1, "B").End(xlToRight))
            .Cells(1) = DateSerial(Mid(.Cells(1).Value2, 3, 4), Right(.Cells(1).Value2, 2), 1)
            .NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
            .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlMonth, Step:=1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]